# MVC CodeFirst one to many relationship creates new data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first

I'm using CodeFirst with MVC 3 and have these two classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Email]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Passwort { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }       
}
```

When adding a new person I want to reference a city to this person. Therefore i'm using a SelectList with all cities in my view. The CityId and the object is transferred correctly to the Post-method, but when saving the changes to the database I will have a new object in the city-table (with same name, but new Id). 
I suggest there's something wrong with the relations in my models. Maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: How do you set your `City` property when saving?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Inside my mapping-method:

`City = Repository.RepositoryManager.Instance.CityRepository.FindWithId(personViewModel.CitySelected.Value)`

I'm searching in the db for the corresponding object...

Comment: Have you tried to decorate CityId property with an `[Identity]` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you give your `Person` model an explicit `CityId` property, then you won't need to retrieve the `City` object from your repository, you can just assign the `CityId` value directly to the `Person` object and save it. For really straightforward views, you don't need to use a viewmodel either, you could receive a `Person` instance into the `POST` action method and `CityId` would already be assigned, assuming the html field in the View has the same name.

This should fix your problem, because you will then know you are explicitly using a CityId that already exists.

Your database will already contain a `Person.City_CityId` field anyway so you're not creating anything new, just giving yourself more control over the situation. Sometimes you may need to use a `[ForeignKey]` attribute in the model to connect the `Person.CityId` property with the virtual property, but using the standard naming convention this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! I had to use the ForeignKey attribute, but now it looks fine :)